How to call a C++ member method from a C callback function with PipeWire
I am trying to adapt this PipeWire example for use with C++, as I need to carry out various processing in a C++ method. But I am not sure how I can call a C++ member method from the static callback function, i.e. from:
static void on_process(void *userdata, struct spa_io_position *position)

Any suggestions?

This question has been asked many times before. You only can do this if you know/have an instance of a class to call.

What have you tried? Have written the C++ method you want to call? Did you try to pass  it? Did you try compiling it? What error or errors do you get?

If an answer solves your problem @Loke, you could click '✔' to mark it as an accepted answer. You can also upvote any helpful answer (see here: What should I do when someone answers my question?).

You can do the following:

Use either a global function, or a static method of your class as a callback. Each has advantages and disadvantages:

A static method has the advantage of packing everything together.
A global function has the advantage of not cluttering the class but requires to make the callback method public or the function a friend.


When you register the callback, pass the addess of the class instance (this pointer if you are inside a method) as the userdata.
In your static/global callback cast userdata back into a pointer to your class instance.
Use the casted pointer to call a method of your class (casted_pointer->...).

Pseudo code (static method variant):
class A
{
    void register_me_for_on_process()
    {
        void * user_data = this;
        register_on_process(on_process_static, user_data, ...);
    }
    
    // Static callback for registering with the API:
    static void on_process_static(void *userdata, ...)
    {
        A * pThis = reinterpret_cast<A*>(userdata);
        pThis->on_process(...);
    }

    // Callback:
    void on_process(...)
    {
    }
};

The global function variant is very similar - just take the on_process_static method out of the class, and make the on_process method public (or make on_process_static a friend).

Don't complect your class design with static methods which don't need access to private and protected member. Also, I find the method naming in your objects somewhat confusing... :-(

@einpoklum I thought that packing the static callback in the class is better than having a free function floating around ...  but I guess it is a matter of personal preference. As for the names - I tried to use names that convey the meaning (based around the callback name that the OP mentioned - on_process). I'm open for suggestions for better ones.

Oh, having free functions is much better! Because it's not something that you need to read and understand in order to use the class; nor does it drag in dependencies the class itself should not have. See also the C++ Core Guidelines item C.4

@einpoklum I added a note about both options. BTW - using a free function mean that the callback must be public (or the free function a friend). Using a static method enables to make the callback private easily, if it's applicable.

This is what userdata is for. For user data.
struct UserData {
   void on_process(struct spa_io_position *position) { /* blabla */ }
};

static void on_process(void *userdata, struct spa_io_position *position)
{
        UserData *ud = static_cast<UserData*>(userdata);
        ud->on_process(position);
}
 
static const struct pw_filter_events filter_events = {
        PW_VERSION_FILTER_EVENTS,
        .process = on_process,
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        struct UserData ud;
        pw_filter_new_simple(blabla, static_cast<void*>(&ud));
}

